# Integrate Google Maps on ios9 and Swift 2 without Podfile

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift2, cocoapods

I am looking to integrate `GoogleMaps` on my app.

Am using **Xcode 7.2, Swift 2** and **I** **don't** want to install it through **podfile**

I searched my best to find an alternative way like Google-Maps framework... Can someone please suggest me any idea...

Answer (score 1):

From [Google Map SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start)

```
Versions 1.9.2 and earlier of the Google Maps SDK for iOS were available as a zip file containing a static framework. There was also the option to install recent versions from a CocoaPods pod. From version 1.10.0 onwards, the Google Maps SDK for iOS is available for installation only via CocoaPods.
```